# How to keep parskip inside environments created with \DeclareNewTOC

Tags: floats, koma-script, parskip

I am using KOMA-Script and `\DeclareNewTOC` to create custom float and inline environments. For my document, I would like to have spacing between paragraphs. I use the `parskip` option of the KOMA-Script class. This option gets applied to the regular paragraphs as expected but not for the paragraphs inside the environments generated by `\DeclareNewTOC`.

How can I generate floating and inline environments which acts exactly like the rest of the document?

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=tip,
  float,
  nonfloat,
]{tip}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-2]
  \begin{tip}
    \caption{Floating}
    \lipsum[3-4]
  \end{tip}
  \lipsum[5]
  \begin{tip-}
    \caption{Inline}
    \lipsum[6-7]
  \end{tip-}
  \lipsum[8-9]
\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use option `atbegin={\KOMAoptions{parskip}}` for the new environments:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=tip,
  float,
  nonfloat,
  atbegin={\KOMAoptions{parskip}}% <- added
]{tip}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-2]
  \begin{tip}
    \caption{Floating}
    \lipsum[3-4]
  \end{tip}
  \lipsum[5]
  \begin{tip-}
    \caption{Inline}
    \lipsum[6-7]
  \end{tip-}
  \lipsum[8-9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some times one misses the obvious. Thanks for helping me out.